# check to see who wins in a dice game

Tags: c++, dice

I have a dice game

```
int userGame()
{
    cout << " User turn --- Press 2 to roll" << endl;
    cin >> userInput;

    if ( userInput == 2 )
    {
        Dice ();
        cout << "The user rolled        Dice 1 =" << die1 << " and Dice 2 = " << die2 << endl;
        cout << "Total = " << die1 + die2 << endl;
    }

    else {
        cout << "Wrong input. Try again";
        //userGame();
    }


    return (die1 + die2);
}
```

and now in int main , I have -

```
int main ()
{
    // set the seed
    srand(time(0));
    userGame();

        while (true)
        {


            if (userGame() == 7 || userGame() == 11)
            {
                cout << "You won" << endl;
                break;
            }

            else if (userGame() == 2)
            {
                cout << "You loose" <<endl;
                break;
            }

            else

            {
                break;

            }


        }




        return 0;
```

Dice ();

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>      // for the time() function
#include<cstdlib>    // for the srand() and rand() functions
using namespace std;
int compInput;
int userInput;
int die1 = 0;
int die2 = 0;
int Dice ()
{

    // roll the first die
    die1 = (rand() % 6 ) + 1;
    // roll the second die
    die2 = (rand() % 6 ) + 1;


}
```

But the output for some reason is not showing up right. Once it will show that the user won when the output is 7 and other time, it would just continue with the game.

What am i doing with the loop in main()?

Thanks

Comment: instead of break; use return false in first two cases.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (userGame() == 7 || userGame() == 11)
```

This line is your problem. C++ uses short circuit evaluation. In this case, if `userGame() == 7` succeeds, it doesn't check the second half. However, if it fails `userGame()` will be called again for the second half, meaning you'll play twice before going into the code section for the if.

```
    while (true)
    {
        int result = userGame();
        if (result == 7 || result == 11)
        {
            cout << "You won" << endl;
            break;
        }
        else if (result == 2)
        {
            cout << "You loose" <<endl;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
```